# Removing old version of R and R studioo from Centos 7

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying do uninstall an old version of R Studio Server in Centos 7:

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep 'studio'
rstudio.x86_64                         2022.02.3+492-1                 @/rstudio-2022.02.3-492-x86_64
rstudio-pm.x86_64                      1.1.4-3                         @/rstudio-pm-1.1.4-3.x86_64
rstudio-server.x86_64                  2022.02.3+492-1                 @/rstudio-server-rhel-2022.02.3-492-x86_64

$ sudo yum list installed | grep 'R'
OpenEXR-libs.x86_64                    1.7.1-8.el7                     @base    
R-4.2.1.x86_64                         1-1                             @/R-4.2.1-1-1.x86_64
R-core.x86_64                          4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
R-core-devel.x86_64                    4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
R-devel.x86_64                         4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
R-java-devel.x86_64                    4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
libRmath.x86_64                        4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
libRmath-devel.x86_64                  4.1.3-1.sdl7                    @puias_computational
openblas-Rblas.x86_64                  0.3.3-2.el7                     @epel    
perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64         2.061-3.el7                     @base    
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64          1:2.061-4.el7                   @base    
perl-PlRPC.noarch                      0.2020-14.el7                   @base    
perl-TermReadKey.x86_64                2.30-20.el7                     @base    
perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64                 4:1.9725-3.el7                  @base    

$ yum remove rstudio-server-rhel-2022.02.3-492-x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
You need to be root to perform this command.

$ sudo yum remove rstudio-server-rhel-2022.02.3-492-x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
No Match for argument: rstudio-server-rhel-2022.02.3-492-x86_64
No Packages marked for removal
$
```

Am I missing something

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run

```
sudo yum remove rstudio.x86_64
```